# How do I call a Silverlight RIA InvokeOperation in a Domain Service using Reactive Extensions?

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive, invoke

Does anyone know how I would call a RIA InvokeOperation using Reactive Extensions? I need to process some data coming from several asynchronous calls in Silverlight once the calls have all completed. In my test I have combined a couple of strings with the results of a query, and now need to add in the results from a call to a RIA Domain Service Invoke method, and am stuck.

My simple test function on the RIA Domain Service side (done non-RX style) looks like this:

```
    [Invoke]
    public string DomainServiceFunction()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
```

On the client side, this old-school bit of code calls the method, and is the part I want to implement with RX:

```
    private void CallDomainServiceFunction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DomainService1 DomainContext = new DomainService1();   
        InvokeOperation invokeOp = DomainContext.DomainServiceFunction(OnInvokeCompleted, null);
    }

    private void OnInvokeCompleted(InvokeOperation invOp)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(invOp.Value);//This prints "hello".
    }
```

I wrote some test code that combines data from several sources (which is where I want to add the RIA InvokeOperation call as well). It is making a tuple out of a couple of strings and an entity returned by a query:

```
    private void PrintProperty1()
    {
        GISDomainContext DomainContext = new GISDomainContext();
        //Query the database to get information for a property using the folio number.
        var loadProperty = from loadOperation in DomainContextExtensions
              .LoadAsync(DomainContext, DomainContext.GetPropertyNoOwnersByFolioQuery("19401006.000"))
                            select loadOperation;
        //Zip up the property entity with a string for testing purposes.
        var Data = Observable.Return("a bit of text ")
            .Zip((Observable.Return("some more text")
            .Zip(loadProperty, (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b))), (a,b) => Tuple.Create(a,b));
        //Add a bit more stuff just to show it can be done.

        //THIS IS WHERE I WOULD ALSO ZIP WITH THE VALUE RETURNED FROM AN InvokeOperation.

        Data.Subscribe
        (
            //When all the required data are prepared then proceed...
            r => //On Next 
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("OnNext: " + r.Item1 + ", " + r.Item2.Item1 + ", " + r.Item2.Item2.Entities.First().folio.ToString());
                //results: "OnNext: a bit of text , some more text, 19401006.000"
                //At this point the data are all now available for further processing.
            },
            r => //On Error
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error in PrintProperty1: " + r.ToString());
            },
            () =>//On Completed
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Completed PrintProperty1");
            }
        );
    }
```

I suspect `FromAsyncPattern` is the key, but apparently Silverlight hides the Begin/End calls that `FromAsyncPattern` expects as parameters

Quoted from [here](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/09/26/calling-web-services-in-silverlight-using-reactivexaml/):

> "An important note for Silverlight!
>
> Silverlight’s web service
> generated client code does something a bit annoying – it hides away
> the BeginXXXX/EndXXXX calls, presumably to make the Intellisense
> cleaner. However, they’re not gone, the way you can get them back is
> by casting the MyCoolServiceClient object to its underlying interface
> (i.e. the LanguageServiceClient object has a generated
> ILanguageServiceClient interface that it implements)"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Silverlight is not hiding anything. The methods just don't exist on the `DomainContext`-derived proxy generated by the RIA Services tools.

But here's an extension method that wraps an `Invoke` operation into an `IObservable`:

```
public static class DomainContextExtensions
{
  // The method takes in an invoke operation proxy method delegate
  // and returns an observable sequence factory
  public static Func<T1, IObservable<TResult>> FromInvokeOperation<T1, TResult>
    (Func<T1, Action<InvokeOperation<TResult>>, object, InvokeOperation<TResult>> operationDelegate)
  {
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(operationDelegate != null, "operationDelegate");
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Func<T1, IObservable<TResult>>>() != null);

    return x1 =>
      {
        // the subject is a storage for the result.
        var subject = new AsyncSubject<TResult>();

        try
        {
          var invokeOperation = operationDelegate(x1, operation =>
            {
              // handle operation results

              if (operation.IsCanceled)
              {
                return;
              }

              if (operation.HasError)
              {
                subject.OnError(operation.Error);
                operation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                return;
              }

              Contract.Assume(operation.IsComplete);
              subject.OnNext(operation.Value);
              subject.OnCompleted();
            }, null);

          // create the operation cancellation object
          var invokeOperationCancellation = Disposable.Create(() =>
          {
            // need to check if the operation has completed before the subscription is disposed
            if (!invokeOperation.IsComplete && invokeOperation.CanCancel)
            invokeOperation.Cancel(); // this might abort the web call to save bandwidth
          });

          // construct a new observable that adds invoke operation cancellation upon dispose
          return Observable.Create<TResult>(obs => new CompositeDisposable(invokeOperationCancellation, subject.Subscribe(obs)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          return Observable.Create<TResult>(obs =>
            {
              obs.OnError(ex);
              return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        }
      };
  }
}
```

This should work, although I haven't tested it.

Usage:

```
var context = ... // get your DomainContext
var param = ... // operation parameter
// This will create the observable:
var o = DomainContextExtensions.FromInvokeOperation</*Parameter type goes here*/, /*Result type goes here*/>(context.YourOperationMethod)(param);
o.Subscribe(...); // subscribe as you wish or build a query
```

You'll have to write additional methods to support invoke operations with different number of parameters.

Comment: That worked, thanks very much. After some effort I also got it working with an input parameter too.

Comment: @user1066012 If it's still interesting, I've improved the implementation. Now it's very close to the RX's `Observable.FromAsyncPattern` implementation, supports a single parameter and doesn't have synchronization issues. Previous code could throw asserts if subscription was disposed just after the RIA operation had finished.

Comment: In case of any questions on the previous comment: current revision (2) of my answer already has the code that I've mentioned in that comment. Further suggestions/questions are welcome.